# AWS amplify configure subdomain for 2 different amplify apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amazon-route53

I have 2 amplify apps.
Amplify dev and amplify staging.

Each apps have their own environment variables.

I setup the first amplify app as follows:

1. Root domain as test.com
2. subdomain as app1.test.com

But when I setup my second amplify app to use the same root domain(test.com), but different subdomain (app2.test.com) I get this error:

**Create domain association failed
One or more domains requested are already associated with another Amplify app**

Answer (score 0):

You should handle dev and staging from the same app, just with different backend and frontend environments for each.

See more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/team-workflows-with-amplify-cli-backend-environments.html